# HelloWorld example returns a syntax error on React

Tags: reactjs

I tried to check all the libraries/packages that I needed to run a simple example of HelloWorld on React.js without success.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
    document.getElementById('example')
);
```

The error is the following:

```
/Users/Silvio/WebstormProjects/untitled/main.js:5
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

I have installed babel and ReactDOM.

Comment: You may have intalled alright but have you configured babel in webpack

Comment: Do you men .babelrc ? I put the following: {
  "presets": ["env"]
}

Comment: You may want to try create-react-app to get started without figuring out Babel configuration right away https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

Comment: I repeat the question of @ShubhamKhatri :  have you configured babel in webpack ?

Comment: your babel presets should include `react` at least

Comment: Why should I use webpack for a simple helloworld ? Configuring babel is not enough ?

Comment: @SilvioS. You don't need webpack for a simple hello world, although in practice module bundlers are used for most projects. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42167477/1572023) or [this gist](https://gist.github.com/csmcanarney/13cc2162c50ec14ee4f59b2c88b81e3f) for more minimal examples that don't require any additional tooling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code itself is correct, but you probably aren't running it properly as it is meant to be run in the browser, not in Node.js. If `require` is used to import dependencies, `main.js` must first be processed by a bundler like [webpack](https://webpack.github.io) before it is ready for use.

The following snippet is essentially the same code that you have posted but the dependencies (`React` and `ReactDOM`) are imported via `script` tags.

```js
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello, world</h1>, document.getElementById("example"))
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello, world</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here Babel, which transpiles JSX (`<h1>Hello, world</h1>`) is provided by the snippet editor. [This minimal example](https://gist.github.com/csmcanarney/13cc2162c50ec14ee4f59b2c88b81e3f) imports Babel as a dependency and transpiles the JSX portion at run time.

Answer (score 1):

In your .babelrc file you need to specify the following

```
  { 
    "presets": ["react", "stage-0", "es2015"] 
  }
```

Also you need to install the above presets like

```
npm install -S babel-preset-react babel-preset-stage-0 babel-preset-es2015
```

Along with that you webpack.config.js must look something like below to enable babel for .js or .jsx file extensions

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './main.js',
  output: { path: __dirname, filename: 'bundle.js' },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,

      }
    ]
  },
};
```

You can refer **[here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/setting-up-react-for-es6-with-webpack-and-babel-2.html)**  and **[here](https://www.codementor.io/tamizhvendan/beginner-guide-setup-reactjs-environment-npm-babel-6-webpack-du107r9zr)** for more details

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this through babel first - with react and stage-0 presets enabled.

We do this for our sample code here:

https://github.com/flexicious/react-redux-datagrid

Comment: I can't see what you are saying. Could you give me more details ? Thanks

Comment: You should start with a boilerplate template, like the one we used from here : https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit